# Tomcat - scaling on a single server

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have an embedded Tomcat application running on an Amazon EC2 instance. The site was getting an increased amount of traffic, so I upgraded to a much larger instance. However, with the same amount of traffic and with a much larger server, the slow down was still there. I increased the maxThreads and the xmx/xms, but that didn't help much.

The server resources used are small on both the web server and the database server (RDS) (less than 10% memory and less than 20% CPU).

Is there anything that can be done to speed up Tomcat? Or should I bite the bullet and use multiple Tomcat instances and a load balancer?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, nothing has changed in the application, just the traffic increased (almost doubled). My assumption was that (more than) doubling the resources (web server and db) should be adequate. I guess it's not that simple.

Comment: No bandwidth issue? If your site takes a lot of bw to run, close to the limit, a more powerful server is not the solution.

Comment: @ringø The bandwidth is high, but AWS should handle it, right? For the specific instance I am using m3 2x large, it is supposed to have high network speed.

Comment: when it is busy you could hit it (the java process) with a kill -3 and see if all the threads are wait for one of the other threads (goes to standard error).

Comment: I ran the thread dump and didn't see anything abnormal. A lot of RUNNING threads reading from the socket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better you don't do anything right now. You obviously don't know what's actually slowing down the application, that's why you were surprised when you upgraded the server and it had no effect.

Instead of randomly doing things like a monkey with a typewriter, hoping that something will help, profile your application (and run load testing against it) and see what are the "heaviest" actions. **Then** decide how to fix it, whether it's with code optimization, architectural changes, load balancing or any other solutions.

Don't guess, know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I created a test instance with the same resources and ran JMeter against it. The problem with testing is that it is hard to simulate the exact traffic patterns (static resources, etc.). Any specific suggestions on that?

Comment: It's hard to say much without knowing anything about your application. I wouldn't necessarily even worry about the exact patterns (or static resources, since they're hardly the bottleneck).

Comment: The application has not changed and the ratio of the pages visited has not changed either. It's just that there is more traffic doing the same exact thing.  Shouldn't increasing resources solve that? I can't think of anything in the application logic that would be disproportionally affected by increased requests. It's just strange...

Comment: Increasing memory and CPU power wouldn't help unless that's what's the bottleneck. You increased the max threads without knowing if it will help or harm the performance (or be irrelevant). What's so hard about profiling the app?

Comment: I see. So what you're saying is that, when you double the traffic without changing anything else on an application, then the bottleneck is not necessarily going to be the CPU or memory, it could be something else. I will profile the application and see where the weakest spot is and see if that can be optimized.

Comment: Exactly. It may be that the application is nicely balanced CPU/memory bound and you would see a ~100% throughput increase when doubling the server's capacity, but that would be quite surprising in any non-trivial application.

Comment: Of course load balancing is a general approach which should guarantee at least near-double performance improvement (provided they don't have shared resources), but it's not a reason not to know how your application behaves in relation to different resources.

Comment: What I am struggling with is why would two servers load balanced be better than one server twice the capacity (aside from cost and redundancy in case of failure).

Comment: Because when you're doing load balancing in a shared-nothing environment, you can see the performance of your `server1` and know that given the same amount of traffic to `server2` the performance will be the same. Then dividing the traffic into 2 will give you twice the performance (in a simplified scenario). However just like doubling the horsepower of a car's motor won't make the car go twice as fast, doubling the power of a server can't automatically double the performance. For example if your application is IO bound, more memory and CPU won't help at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98315/discussion-between-stepanian-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 2):

[stepanian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182289/stepanian), even though I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'slow down', I had a similar case a few months back, when a huge spike of traffic (some viral campaign) caused our tomcat to behave really weird, even though the bottleneck was NOT on the disk, cpu or memory.

In our case, changing the `Connector` [configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) basically solved the problem, especially understanding the:

- acceptCount
- acceptorThreadCount
- maxConnections
- maxThreads

Hope this helps!  : )